# Simulate a table with multiple rows just with SELECT statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

If I can do the following select statement to create a table with one value

```
 SELECT 'myname' AS 'Name'
```

this will return a table with column = Name and one value = myname

how can I work around this to return one column with multiple values from just the select statement

I don't want to do this :

```
 DECLARE @tmp TABLE (Name varchar(50)) 

 INSERT INTO @tmp (Name) VALUES ('myname1'),('myname2') 
    SELECT * FROM @tmp
```

**Just** from a single `SELECT` statement if  possible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're wanting to simulate a table with multiple rows just with `SELECT` statement, this can typically be done with `UNION` of rows:

```
SELECT 'myname1' AS 'Name' UNION
SELECT 'myname2' UNION
SELECT 'myname3'
-- etc
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12433

Comment: brilliant idea i wouldn't think about doing it this way :) Thanks

Comment: Using `UNION` is simply not the best approach.  This should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

Or, you can use the multiple VALUES in the SELECT, like:

```
SELECT [Name]
FROM (VALUES ('myname1'),('myname2')) AS X([name])
```

Comment: This is the best approach and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I didn't know you could simply provide VALUES directly into a FROM clause; that's very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to simulate sequential data like in your example.You can define a recursive `CTE` and use it like a table.

Below code will generate 10 records

```
;With Users as
(
    Select 1 as ID, CAST('Username1' AS varchar(25)) as Name
        union all
    Select ID + 1 , CAST('Username'+CAST(ID+1 AS varchar(5) ) AS varchar(25))
        from Users
        where ID < 10
)
SELECT * FROM Users
```

Here is SQL Fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12452

But CTE cannot be used in  multiple statements.If you need to use it in multi statements. Then insert data from CTE to Temp Table or Table Variable.