# Simulate table with just select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Similar question to [Simulate a table with multiple rows just with SELECT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979658/simulate-a-table-with-multiple-rows-just-with-select-statement) - this question asks for a **single column** of multiple rows.

How can I simulate a table with **multiple columns** and rows?

I have gotten this far (for multiple columns single row):

```
SELECT 'John Doe' AS [Customer Name],
       '31' AS [Customer Age],
       'pizza' AS [Food]
```

But unsure how to get multiple rows of data.

Using sql-server

Comment: You could `UNION ALL` between multiple instances of this same `SELECT` with different data.  Though I imagine making an actual table, even just an in-memory one as a variable, would be more ideal.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your requirements?  If you need just a few rows, then `UNION ALL` would probably do.  If you need to generate a large set, then writing a script in SQL Server, or maybe importing a data set would be more appropriate.

Comment: Just trying to mock a table for testing purposes (so only like 3-4 rows). I would like unique data in each row.

Comment: The referenced duplicate was not specific to SQL Server -- and the accepted answer uses `union` rather than `union all` which is not the best solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886449/is-it-possible-to-have-a-tableless-select-with-multiple-rows) is a superset of this one. It asks for standard or proprietary solutions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `values` table constructor:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM (VALUES ('John Doe', 31, 'pizza'),
             ('John Doe', 31, 'pizza')
     ) v(customer_name, customer_age, food);
```

Notes:

- Don't use spaces in your column names.  They just make it harder to write queries.
- `age` is a bad column to have.  Instead, you should have date-of-birth.
- Just repeat the value lists with the values that you want.

Answer (score 2):

Using `CROSS JOIN` as a quick hack

```
SELECT 'John Doe' AS [Customer Name],
       '31' AS [Customer Age],
       'pizza' AS [Food]
from (select 1 as x) x
cross join (select 1 as ID union select 2 union select 3) y
```

Or based off your comments, you are better off just creating some dummy data...

```
declare @table table ([Customer Name] varchar(64), [Customer Age] int, [Food] varchar(64))
insert into @table
values
('John Doe',31,'Pizza'),
('New Doe',15,'Fish'),
('Frank Doe',66,'Crackers'),
('John McGee',91,'Sausage')

select * from @table
```

Comment: is it possible to do this and get unique rows, i.e. 'Bob dylan', '18', 'burgers', ...

Comment: Well, you'd have to give a list of names... but if you are going to do that you may as well just create a  table of dummy data... i'll update

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:** `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT
    [Customer Name] = 'John Doe',
    [Customer Age] = 31,
    Food = 'pizza'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    [Customer Name] = 'Jane Doe',
    [Customer Age] = 25,
    Food = 'cake'
```

You just need to supply column names on the 1st set:

```
SELECT
    [Customer Name] = 'John Doe',
    [Customer Age] = 31,
    Food = 'pizza'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jane Doe', 25, 'cake' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jane Doe', 16, 'coke' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jane Doe', 19, 'salad'
```

**Option 2:** `VALUES`

```
SELECT
    T.[Customer Name],
    T.[Customer Age],
    T.Food
FROM
    (VALUES
    ('John Doe', 31, 'pizza'),
    ('Jane Doe', 25, 'cake')
    ) AS T([Customer Name], [Customer Age], Food)
```

I recommend 2nd approach, as you can enforce the data type you need, for example:

```
SELECT
    [Customer Name] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), T.[Customer Name]),
    [Customer Age] = CONVERT(TINYINT, T.[Customer Age]),
    Food = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), T.Food)
FROM
    (VALUES
    ('John Doe', 31, 'pizza'),
    ('Jane Doe', 25, 'cake')
    ) AS T([Customer Name], [Customer Age], Food)
```

Using `VALUES`, you can also join directly against other tables (or apply functions) without wrapping the `SELECT` in a CTE or subquery.

However, I recommend ***neither*** if you want to mock a table for testing purposes (and specially if you are testing performance), as both these approaches will require you to significantly change the statement you are currently testing. For this just create a temporary table with the exact definition as the one you want to mock and load the data there.